# Effective way to perform image processing algorithms over Texture2D

Tags: xna, texture2d

I have a situation where I need to apply some algorithm to my texture every time it's rotated.

My question is - what is the best approach to apply an image processing algorithms within XNA?

Now the texture is a RenderTarget2D and the algorithm performs some operation with it's pixels and sets them back to the RenderTarget2D. This approach causes termination of my app and it's performance is very bad.

I searched through the stackoverflow but have no found anything relevant to the subject.
I also read this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/04/14/stalling-the-pipeline.aspx and understand how bad my approach is.

Comment: It depends on what the algorithm is, how often you apply it, and when you need to apply it (compile time, load time, run time?). Can you give more details?

Comment: Andrew, this algorithm is applied in run time(every time the texture is rotated). Considering that the texture can be rotated in every Update means that the algorithm should be applied before every Draw.

Comment: Really this is a performance question. Reading from a render target is one option. Using a pixel shader is generally the fastest method - but has many limitations - and then a host of techniques for overcoming those limitations. I'd need to know more information about the algorithm before I can narrow it down. Also what, exactly, do you mean by "rotated"? Are you moving vertices? Texture co-ordinates? Or something more complicated?

Comment: How many possible rotations have you got? If it's 4 or 8 or..., it might be relevant to generate them offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the operations that you may require, then doing them through an HLSL shader would be a very good idea.

Shaders are really the right choice because you can take advantage of the multiple cores the GPU has AND you don't need to resolve the data in the rendertarget; the data gets process on its way to the screen without causing any stalling.